# Ansible - Using Jinja 2 for Dynamic Roles

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to make an Ansible playbook that that that calls rolls dynamically. Now, Ansible doesn't support that natively, so I thought I could circumvent this with some Jinja2 templates... but I'm not even sure how to actually do that. So let's say I have a list of roles in a variable

```
role_vars:
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3
```

My template:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles: >
    {%- for name in role_vars %}
    {{- '- ' + name + '\n    ' -}}
    {%- endfor %}
```

I'd assume it should yield something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3
```

but I can't get it to work. So how do I? Is it even possible to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed too much trimming modifiers. Try this:
Template:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    {% for name in role_vars -%}
    - {{ name }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I ran it and it gives me:

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in file.yml': line 23, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

 roles:
   {% for name in role_vars -%} .........
  

I'm under the impression you need a '>' to pipe it in for ansible to recognize the jinja2, but that also gave me an error.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you then... This template is not supposed to be fed to ansible-playbook directly, but as `template` module source. It is not ansible way to use jinja2 in playbooks like this.

Comment: What I realized was that the '>' symbol is supposed to denote inline templating. Obviously this can lead to messy scenarios, and it's not intended to be used  a lot either. But as you said in this case using the module is better, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: test
    set_fact: var=[{% for i in groups['server'] %}{% if hostvars[i].clusterName is defined %}"{{ hostvars[i].clusterName }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
  - name: debug
    debug: msg={{ var }},{{ var | length }}
```